# why Spark executor needs to connect with Worker

Tags: apache-spark

When I kicked off one Spark job I will find the Executor startup command line as following:

```
bin/java -cp /opt/conf/:/opt/jars/* -Xmx1024M -Dspark.driver.port=56559 
org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend 
--driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.1.140.2:56559 
--executor-id 1 --hostname 10.1.140.5 --cores 2 
--app-id app-20161221132517-0000 
--worker-url spark://Worker@10.1.140.5:56451
```

From above command we would find the line `--worker-url spark://Worker@10.1.140.5:56451`,that's I'm curious about, why Executor needs to communicate with Worker, in my mind executor only needs to talk with other executors and Driver.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can see in the above image that `Executors are part of worker nodes`.

**Application** :   User program built on Spark. Consists of a `driver program and executors` on the cluster.

**Worker node** :   Any node that can `run application code` in the cluster

**Executor** :  A process launched for an application `on a worker node`, that `runs tasks and keeps data in memory or disk` storage across them. Each application has its own executors.

[Source](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Executor fate is connected with the worker fate. If worker is abnormally terminated executors have to be able to detect this fact and stop themselves. Without this process one could end up with "ghost" executors.